# Issue with SubString function

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, substring

Trying to use the .NET SubString function. I pass a value to a custom function and then an if statement evaluates if it should be capitalized or not. Then I use the following to change the first letter to upper case. However, it tells me that the "Index was outside the bounds of the array." What am I doing wrong?

```
char.ToUpper(X[0]) + X.Substring(1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your string is not empty?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I'll set another break point and check , it wasn't when I looked earlier but some things have changed since then.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin You were right, looks like I've got some backtracking to do. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, it's not the C# SubString function. It's the .NET SubString function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in isNullOrEmpty()

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(X)) 
{
  char.ToUpper(X[0]) + X.Substring(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out, as it has some sanity checks included

```
public string FirstLetterToUpper(string str)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return str;

     return char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: `Substring(1)` should work normally for one-character strings.

Comment: Index out of range means that the string is not null